# Как диагонально растянуть текстуру

Tags: java, libgdx

Как растянуть текстуру по диагонали?
Т.е что бы она была похожа на параллелограмм

Comment: Использовать шейдеры.

Comment: Можно пример использования шейдеров?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ!
Кому интересно

в Create

```
        String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n" +
            "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" +
            "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 u_worldView;\n" +
            "varying vec4 v_color;" +
            "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
            "void main()                  \n" +
            "{                            \n" +
            "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); \n" +
            "   v_texCoords = a_texCoord0; \n" +
            "   gl_Position =  u_worldView * a_position;  \n"      +
            "}                            \n" ;

    String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" +
            "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "#endif\n" +
            "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
            "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
            "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" +
            "void main()                                  \n" +
            "{                                            \n" +
            "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n"+
            "}";

    mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6, VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.  ColorUnpacked(), VertexAttribute.TexCoords(0));
    mesh.setIndices(new short[] {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0});
    shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

В Render

```
        sprite9.getTexture().bind();
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView",camera.combined);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    for (int i=(int)(rect.getPosition().x+10);i<(int)(rect.getPosition().x+80);i++){
        mesh.setVertices(new float[]
                {race[i].x, race[i].y-0.7f, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
                        race[i].x, race[i].y, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                        race[i+1].x, race[i+1].y, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                        race[i+1].x, race[i+1].y-0.7f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1
                });
        mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    }
    shader.end();
```

Это у меня рисовалась поверхность трассы.
Че за значения в меше и в шеййдерах я не знаю, может кто разьяснит в комментах 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]